# Запятая после присоединительных союзов: почему Розенталь дает разное решение?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, союзы

**1) Сложноподчиненное предложение (постановка запятой зависит от союза):**

1) как правило, **после союза И запятая не ставится**:  **И хотя погода значительно улучшилась**, опасность засухи не миновала;

2) после присоединительного **союза А** запятая не ставится: **А когда взошло солнце**, перед нами открылся вид на снеговую вершину;

3) после **союза НО** запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.: **Но, если далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих,** пехота снова бросалась в атаку (Сим.); **Но когда он, опираясь на палку,** вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… что-то защемило в ране (Павл.);

4) после союза **ОДНАКО** запятая обычно ставится: **Однако, если обстоятельства того потребуют**, я в стороне стоять не буду.

**2) Деепричастный оборот (запятая ставится)**

То же после присоединительного союза, которым начинается предложение (союз стоит после точки): **Но, рассмотрев всесторонне своё положение в роли мужа Вареньки**, он засмеялся (М. Т.); **И, подойдя ко мне**, сказал…

**3) Обстоятельственные обороты  (У Розенталя информации нет)**

В ПАС есть пример с союзом НО: **Но, вопреки возможному,** солнце вышло ярко-красное, и всё в мире порозовело, покраснело (Сол.);

Если взять предлог НЕСМОТРЯ НА, то после союза И все старательно пишут запятую, так как сам оборот обособляется по правилам в большинстве случаев. А надо ли это делать?

Примеры:

**И несмотря на то**, что до моего дома шел без пересадки трамвай, я предпочитала идти пешком… [Дина Рубина (2015)]

**И несмотря на свою неприязнь** к твердо стоящему на стороне обвинения Тимуру Ахмедовичу, Дзюба не мог не признать, что начинает испытывать к этому человеку нечто вроде симпатии. [Александра Маринина (2014)]

**И несмотря на текущее падение цен на золото**, долгосрочная потребность в нем возрастает в связи с дестабилизацией мировой валютной системы и международной обстановки. [«Эксперт», 2014]

**ВЫВОД**: Может быть, не надо рассматривать конкретные союзы, а ориентироваться **на формальное решение**: если перестановка оборота/предложения невозможна, то запятая не пишется; если перестановка возможна, то автор выбирает подходящий вариант во всех случаях.  Другой вариант ― это **дать каждому союзу дополнительную характеристику** по его возможности присоединяться к обороту, образуя единую конструкцию.

Answer (score 1):

В правилах пунктуации за длительное время сложилась система *условностей*, которые преимущественно держатся **не** на интонации (расстановке "препинаний"), а на учебном грамматическом разборе предложения (в приоритете - обособляемые или отделяемые запятой конструкции). Во многих случаях появляются "лишние" запятые, мешающие чтению с естественной расстановкой пауз. Например, таковы запятые, появляющиеся по внешним причинам после союза "и": пауза возникает в таких местах разве что при произнесении тостов, когда "тостующий" забывает что-то или силится сочинить продолжение речи. В случае с "но" речевая пауза факультативна и может обозначаться как в устной, так и в письменной речи - помимо запятой, в неформальных текстах вроде постов в форумах можно встретить двоеточие и даже восклицательный знак, когда хотят привлечь внимание к последующему. В своих рекомендациях Розенталь редко ссылается на интонацию, да и возможности что-либо изменить в сложившихся правилах в пользу интонации у него не было. Видимо, отсюда и возникли такие часто используемые им ориентиры, как "*тесная связь*", которую не всегда можно строго обосновать, и "*изымаемость оборота без нарушения смысла*" (напр. при пунктуации в оборотах с "если" при наличии или отсутствии "то" - в его здешнем примере с появлением "то" запятая между "но" и "если" исчезла бы независимо от интонации).

Если пофантазировать о гипотетической реформе (в интересах соответствия между пунктуацией и интонацией), то могу высказать лишь своё отношение к запятым после "и" и "но": на мой взгляд, такую запятую (появившуюся на основании любого формального правила) можно было бы "постановить" отбрасывать в случаях противоречия интонации, поскольку учебный разбор - задача второстепенная; прикладной характер пунктуации - важнее. Если же пауза автору понадобится по особым риторическим причинам, можно на месте циркулярной запятой поставить многоточие.

Comment: Как мне кажется, в устной речи все присоединительные союзы (кроме ОДНАКО) произносятся без паузы и логического выделения, то есть постановка или отсутствие запятой определяется только по грамматическому принципу (не по интонации). Если нельзя переставить оборот, то союз однозначно относится к нему. А если можно переставить, то какой смысл в выделении оборота запятыми на письме (в устной речи он не выделяется)?

Comment: Особенно это касается присоединительного  союза И, который и правда похож на частицу. И зачем его обязательно обособлять, эта запятая после И в начале предложения как-то не смотрится, тем более что частицы можно присоединять, например,  к деепричастному обороту. Сравнить: И, подойдя ко мне, сказал. - И только подойдя ко мне, сказал. Добавили частицу, и уже перестановка невозможна.