Деепричастный оборот после союза (в начале предложения) — нужна ли запятая?
1. Но долго находясь на чужбине, чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
2. А уезжая в командировку, всегда целовал нас, детей.

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437948/%d0%9d%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f

Промчалась по вашей ссылке, shampar... Но не увидела там ни одного словечка о деепричастных оборотах.

• Из правил Розенталя:

2. Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения): Наш отец Чимша-Гималайский был из кантонистов, но, выслужив офицерский чин, оставил нам потомственное дворянство и именьишко (Ч.)...
То же после присоединительного союза, которым начинается предложение (союз стоит после точки): Но, рассмотрев всесторонне своё положение в роли мужа Вареньки, он засмеялся (М. Т.); И, подойдя ко мне, сказал…
Исключение составляют те случаи, когда деепричастный оборот (или одиночное деепричастие) стоит после противительного союза а (деепричастную конструкцию невозможно изъять из предложения или переставить в другое место без разрушения структуры предложения)...

• В первом предложении я бы поставила запятую:
Но, долго находясь на чужбине, чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
(Можно переставить деепричастный оборот: Но чувствуешь, долго находясь на чужбине, что хочется домой.)
Пример:
Разумеется, дроны пытались отстреливаться. Но, быстро перемещаясь между ними, я легко уходил с линии огня... (Дмитрий Гришанин. Рихтовщик).
• Во втором предложении — нет:
А уезжая в командировку, всегда целовал нас, детей.
(Перестановка оборота невозможна.)
Пример:
А уезжая на лесозаготовки, специально напомнил: проследи за отелом (Федор Абрамов. Две зимы и три лета).
Деепричастные конструкции
Дополнение из ПАС (§ 68):

Деепричастный оборот, находящийся после союза или союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (союзы не включаются в деепричастный оборот)...
<...>
Исключение составляет союз а...


В общем, фразы не самодостаточные, но начинаются с сочинительных союзов, поэтому понять, нужна ли запятая, без понимания, к чему относится сочинительный союз, нельзя наверняка.
Приезжая на заграничный курорт, поначалу очень радуешься, особенно солнцу. Но, долго находясь на чужбине, чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
Поначалу, но.
...поначалу руешься, но чувствуешь, хочется домой.
Отдыхая первые несколько дней на курорте, очень радуешься, особенно солнцу. Но долго находясь на чужбине, чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
"первые несколько дней, но долго" - противопоставлены два деепричастных оборота, НО входит в состав одного из них. Если выкинуть второй оборот оставив но, получается чепуха:
Отдыхая первые несколько дней на курорте, очень радуешься, особенно солнцу. Но чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
Во первом же предложении, если выкинуть деепричастный оборот, получится следующее:
А всегда целовал нас, детей.
Можно ли придумать контекст, когда такое написание оправдано?
Пусть ты и не родной отец! пусть! А, уезжая в командировку, всегда целовал нас, детей.
То есть "А" в смысле "НО". Запятую поставить можно, но зависит от контекста до союза. Но можно и не ставить.

Классный у вас разбор! Как раз хотела написать сюда примерно то же самое, но только общими фразами: как надо учитывать контекст. А у вас прямо конкретные примеры.  Трудно придумать. Правила они правилами, но и авторское понимание пунктуации тоже не надо забывать.  Правда союз А я бы не стала анализировать,пусть входит оборот. После него и паузу не сделаешь, это уже структура на первом месте. А вот союз НО - это действительно выбор.

@Sharon Что-то посмотрел я, что написал, а там запятых столько не хватает... Об одной думаешь, десять пропускаешь)

Да ладно, это в рабоче порядке)  Мне всегда хотелось увидеть на примерах, как контекст влияет на знаки.

"Отдыхая первые несколько дней, заграничный курорт очень радует..." Курорт сам отдыхает? Прикольно!))

@ЛюдмилаПетрикова - это коварные галлицизмы). Посмотрите, так лучше?)

Лучше) А тут ужасно: "Приезжая на заграничный курорт, поначалу очень все радует".)) Спасибо за пример с союзом А, когда его можно обособить. Такую ситуацию очень трудно придумать, а, хорошенько подумав, вы справились))

Мое решение для союза НО:
Но долго находясь на чужбИне, // чувствуешь, / что хочется домОй.
Пояснение

В предложении достаточно запятых, еще одна здесь ни к чему  При постановке запятой деепричастный оборот приобретает вставочную интонацию, так что предложение будет делиться на 4 части, что нежелательно. Поэтому относим союз НО к деепричастному обороту, произношение в одну фразу.

А разве это возможно, по правилам всегда надо ставить запятую? А  давайте приглядимся к деепричастному обороту и обратим внимание на инверсию наречия долго. Просто так слова не переставляют.


Сравнить: Но, находясь на чужбине долгое время, // чувствуешь, / что хочется домой.
Вот здесь поставим запятую по правилам.
P. S. О присоединительных союзах
Розенталь подробно рассматривает эту тему для придаточных предложений, но этого нет в теме для деепричастных оборотов. Допустим, что после союза НО нужно обязательно и всегда ставить запятую, в чем я не уверена. А как быть после союза И, неужели тоже обязательно?  И почему такие разные правила? Вот кто бы это объяснил?
Ну и практика должна показать: запятая после всех ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫХ союзов пред деепричастием ставится строго обязательно.  А иначе слушаться не хочется)
Кстати, в ПАС про присоединительные союзы информации нет.
Первый попавшийся пример:
Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 3 (1978)
Ну и мы не даем свою — так в чем же дело? — И сказав это, он сразу же заторопился: вынул чистый лист бумаги, положил его на стол и сказал: — Ну что ж, Владимир Михайлович, зафиксируем?
А это очень давно  я задавала вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434469/Запятая-после-присоединительных-союзов-почему-Розенталь-дает-разное-решение
Еще добавлю.  Присоединительные союзы относятся ко всему предложению, и они считаются таковыми по отношению к предыдущему тексту. И если мы обособляем деепр. оборот, то это уже проблемы этого оборота, который мы хотим или не хотим сделать вставкой.

А вот здесь есть запятая. Кто Сакко и Ванцетти на электрический стул посадил? Присяжные. Классовый суд! Как его ни обставляй, ни ограничивай, он свою власть в обиду все равно не даст. Ну и мы не даем свою — так в чем же дело? — И, сказав это, он сразу же заторопился... (http://www.e-kniga.ru/Dombrovs/fakultet17.html). В шести текстах из девяти запятая имеется.

И что? Это всего лишь разные решения.

Уважаемые дамы и господа и другие товарищи)))
Я хочу вот что еще сказать, упустила, наверное.  Если я обособляю оборот, я не могу выделить ударением нужные мне слова (долго или на чужбине), потому что весь оборот уходит на второй план, становится вставкой.
(1) Но дОлго находясь на чужбине, // чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
Но долго находясь на чужбИне, // чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
(2)  Но,  // долго находясь на чужбине, // чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
Как произносится вставочный оборот?  Верно, вы не знаете, как он произносится, если решили его обособить!))
Это не только две паузы, но и общее понижение голоса, увеличенный темп. Оборот становится дополнительной информацией, уходит из основного состава. Остается только: Но чувствуешь, что хочется домой.
А подчеркиваются нужные слова как раз по контексту, противопоставляя, например, пары сначала/долго, на чужбине/домой.  Разве не надо и об этом тоже подумать?
